# How to get rsync creditals for google storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud storage for my jekyll website. I can upload to bucket files using this command:

```
gsutil -m rsync -d -r . gs://yay.dinopacks.com
```

But how to get just credentials login:password for the my bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need login:password. Use a service account and authorize it(by assigning a relevant IAM role) to write objects to your bucket.

When you create a service account, you'd given the JSON key file for that account. You could then use the key file to authorize your login to GCS.

Comment: You can review the available Access Control options in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/).
Another alternative is to login using your GCP [user credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

Comment: https://buddy.works/